# Vue server and django running on same machine, django server not able to fetch client files

Tags: django, vue.js, django-webpack-loader

I am trying to run vuejs server and django server on a same machine. It works very well on my local machine where django by default runs on http://127.0.0.1:8000 and vue.config.js has public path listed as 0.0.0.0:8080. But when I run this on my remote machine, I start the django server like ‘python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000’ and to access my django server, I hit the browser with {{ubuntu_machine_ip}}:8000. The browser console complains saying app.js could not be found.

I am pretty much sure I am passing wrong IP onto my vue.config.js but couldn't figure out what the IP would be.

I have tried 127.0.0.1:8080 but could not make it work. Added my vue.config.js baseUrl settings.

const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");

module.exports = {
    baseUrl: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/",
    '''
}